# Inform service about finished job so he could be stopped

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have `Service`, that in `onStart` I'm calling to existing `AsyncTask <>`  from new `Thread`.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                //code that fetch data 
            }
                 myTask taskA = new myTask ();
                 taskA.execute();
        }

    };
    thread.start();

}
```

After the work in `taskA`  is finished, how he can inform Service so he can be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should override both onStart and onStartCommand in a service to accommodate for all range of Android devices.

Regarding stopping a service from within you can you `stopSelf()` to do that.

Comment: In what point I should call stopSelf()? how can I know that AsyncTask I started is finished?

Comment: You can override onPostExecute and call it there